# Strip (remove) pagination base (pagination_base) ("page" slug in url) of WordPress Archive

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I'm looking for a solution (php code / wordpress plugin) **strip (remove)** pagination base (pagination_base) of WordPress Archive.

The WordPress Archive page list the Posts by Category.

***Default Wordpress Archive page when pagination have "page" slug in URL (On Category Archive Page):***

***domain.com/category-name/page/2***

I want remove the "page" in the url:

***domain.com/category-name/2***

***Default Wordpress Archive page when pagination have "page" slug in URL (On Front Page):***

***domain.com/page/2***

I want remove the "page" in the url:

***domain.com/2***

I found the way to rename only :(
(rename "page" to "p" in pagination slug url).

**The code for rename:**

```
function my_custom_pagination_base() {
   global $wp_rewrite;
   $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = 'p';
   $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

Thanks